# I need to create a Lambda function that returns a code based on text spoken by user

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I would like to create an Alexa skill where user will approximately say the CodeDesc which can't be really controlled for 100% accurate as per stored DB entry but Alexa still returns the code for the text (eg. Expense Code)

I am thinking to create a DynamoDB table with two columns which will look something like -

```
 SomeCode - Alphanumeric 20 chars

 CodeDesc - Description of the code - large text say 1000 chars.
```

I am looking for a way to take that spoken-english style description and look up in DynamoDB for the text that is best match in table and fetch the code/s that can be read back to user with description and associated code.

I'll try to elaborate a practical application of it.

```
Alexa, what is the expense code for Travel expenses for visiting ACME Kansas office?
```

Table entry is-

```
 SomeCode - A34342 
 SomeDesc - Travel expenses
```

Alexa says - The code for Travel Expenses is A34342.

Answer (score 0):

Use Slots. You can get the keywords in CodeDesc table through slots.

> Eg: Alexa, what is the expense code for [codeDesc] for visiting ACME
>   Kansas office?

Where **[codeDesc]** is a custom slot and you have slot values defined for that slot type.

This way when user says

> Alexa, what is the expense code for Travel expenses for visiting ACME
>   Kansas office?

the **travel expenses** keyword will be sent as a value for the slot type **[codeDesc]** to your API and you can get the corresponding someCode from Db and build your response.

More on [slots](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/create-intents-utterances-and-slots.html)

Hope this helps!